# Excel FILTER() returning 0 for blank cells

Tags: excel, filter, worksheet-function, is-empty, excel-365

I suspect this has been asked previously, but I can't find it.

`FILTER()` will often return a 0 for blank rows, even when a return string is specified.

Using `filter()` I am often getting a 0 return value for empty cells. Assume these 6 rows of data in column A:

```
abc
xyz
abc

xyz
abc
```

If I use

```
FILTER(A10:A15, A10:A15 <> "xyz", "")
```

I get back the following (sometimes):

```
abc
abc
  0
abc
```

This seems to be somewhat unpredictable. Having 0s show up where I don't want is a problem and requires extra logic or filtering. Is this a known issue? Other than explicitly filtering out blank cells, is there another way to solve this problem?

This seems to work to get rid of 0 returning for empty cells:

```
FILTER(A10:A15, (A10:A15 <> "xyz") * (A10:A15 <> ""), "")
```

This is returned:

```
abc
abc
abc
```

I can live with this solution but it should be unnecessary. I also end up explaining why I'm filtering empty cells to people over and over.

btw, filtering out 0 doesn't work. `FILTER()` seems to see the cell as a blank string when reading it, but not when outputting the result.

```
FILTER(A10:A15, (A10:A15 <> "xyz") * (A10:A15 <> 0), "")
```

This will return the original results with the 0.

If there is no better solution, is there an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/06/17/excel-filter-function/), the third argument (If_empty) is not for cases when there is a blank.

> `FILTER(array, include, [if_empty])`

Where:
**Array** (required) - the range or array of values that you want to filter.
**Include** (required) - the criteria supplied as a Boolean array (TRUE and FALSE values).
Its height (when data is in columns) or width (when data is in rows) must be equal to that of the array argument.
**If_empty** (optional) - the value to return when no entries meet the criteria.

Your function would return the string specified in `If_empty` if all the values in `Array` were "xyz". I.e., the criteria in `Include` would not evaluate to TRUE for any non-blank value in the range `Array`.

Also, it seems that your last formula does not anymore return zeros:
[image: filter does not return zeros]

Comment: Thanks much for the explanation. I can't get the issue I had when filtering using 0 to reproduce. Maybe it was fixed or maybe my eyes weren't working.

Answer (score 7):

You may add &"" in front of your array argument.

For example,

```
FILTER(A10:A15 &"", (A10:A15 <> "xyz") * (A10:A15 <> ""), "")
```

This will work fine with text values but it will convert your numeric data to text, in which case, you may convert it back to numeric using the VALUE function.

Suppose if A10:A15 was numeric data, you may use:

```
VALUE(FILTER(A10:A15 &"", (A10:A15 > 1000) * (A10:A15 <> ""), ""))
```

Comment: Seems like a very obvious solution now that you've shared it. Thanks much.

Answer (score 6):

#### Solution for mixed data ranges

Other solutions mentioned here, will not work correctly when your range contains mixed data. The solutions work for ***either all textual data or all numerical data***. But these won't work for mixed data, as you can see in the comparison below.

This will work with mixed data:

##### **`=FILTER( IF(A10:A15="", "", A10:A15), A10:A15<>"xyz")`**

.

#### Comparing solutions

*Note 1: Orange fields are incorrect/undesired, green ones are correct.*

*Note 2: "Waarde" is Dutch for "value" (error).*

##### Original data and basic filter `=FILTER(I3:K6; I3:I6 <> "")`

[image]

##### `FILTER(... & "")` filter — `=FILTER(I3:K6 & ""; I3:I6 <> "")`

[image: Same as with the SUBSTITUTE() solution.]
*Same as with the `SUBSTITUTE()` solution.*

##### `VALUE(...)` filter — `=VALUE(FILTER(I3:K6; I3:I6 <> ""))`

[image]

##### `VALUE(FILTER(... & ""))` filter — `=VALUE(FILTER(I3:K6 & ""; I3:I6 <> ""))`

[image]

##### ✨ Perfect  filter — `=FILTER(IF(I3:K6 = ""; ""; I3:K6); I3:I6 <> "")`

[image]

##### *Some explanation for the bot :)*

If a cell in the range is empty, it will be an empty string (`""`) else it will use the original value. This way only specific cells will be replaced with textual empty cell, leaving numeric cells as-is for Excel to auto-interpret as numeric or other data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Awesome!! This works great for filtering ranges with *mixed* data. The other solutions only work for either all numeric data or all textual data.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out what seems to be a different generic solution: replace empty stings in the first argument to single quotes, so generically:

```
=FILTER(SUBSTITUTE($X:$Z,"","'"),*whatever*,*whatever*)
```

or in the case of this question:

```
=FILTER(SUBSTITUTE($A10:A15,"","'"),A10:A15 <> "xyz", "")
```

I simply makes use of how Excel handles the single quote, I haven't found any downsides yet, though I didn't test it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Another, less elegant solution, is to **replace empty cells in your source array with a space character** " ".

I found this thread while looking for a quick answer while reformatting data.  So adding a space was quicker that the other solutions.  I really like that
**VALUE**(FILTER(   **&""**, answer as well!

Comment: That will work, but I can't add spaces to every empty cell I encounter. Many of the spreadsheets I'm filtering aren't mine and adding spaces could have unknown side effects.

Answer (score 0):

FOR NUMRIC DATA YOU CAN DO LIKE THIS

IF(ISBLANK(FILTER(...)),"",FILTER(...))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).