# How can I return blank cells as it is instead of printing as Zeros while using filter function

Tags: excel, validation, filter, zero, tensorflow-data-validation

["referring to the data shown in the image while using the filter function and getting the return values, How can I return blank cells as it is instead of printing as Zeros while using filter function"]

[image]

```
=FILTER(A2:C13,A2:A13=E1," ")
```

referring to the data shown in the image while using the filter function and getting the return values, How can I return blank cells as it is instead of printing as Zeros while using filter function

Comment: If no zeros are expected, you could use `=SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(A2:C13,A2:A13=E1," "),0,"")`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, i am sure using `SUBSTITUTE()` will replace the `0` in `10` and hence return as `1`. So it wont be right to use.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=LET(x,IF(A2:C13="","",A2:C13),FILTER(x,TAKE(x,,1)=E1))
```

---

Another possible way could be adding `&""` in front of your array argument. Note that it will convert your numeric values to text so you can use a `VALUE()` function or multiple by `1` to convert it back to numeric when required for further calculation.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E8`

```
=FILTER(A2:C13&"",A2:A13=E1," ")
```

---

Or, you can use as proposed by **[VBasic2008](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9814069/vbasic2008)** Sir

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E14`

```
=FILTER(IF(A2:C13="","",A2:C13),A2:A13=E1," ")
```

---

Comment: Your 2nd solution is converting numbers to strings. Maybe add `=FILTER(IF(A2:C13="","",A2:C13),A2:A13=E1," ")`.

Comment: Yeah I have mentioned that.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the explanation. I guess it's a bit too late.

Comment: Sir sorry I was updating the post with your alternative, also you dont have to be sorry about it. Thanks for sharing your thoughts =)

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs, it's been a great help!

Comment: @user21810668 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of solving it. I would say changing the Excel configuration would be the **first option** to consider to solve this issue since it doesn't require modifying the original formula: **File -> Options -> Advanced** and unmark the following highlighted option: **Show a zero in cells that have zero value**:

[image: Excel Options]

It applies only to the selected worksheet. Here is the output:

[image: output]

Not having this option available, for example when using Excel Web, then you need to use a formula. **I prefer not to change the data type of the output** and to **do the transformation in the output rather than in the input**, because the output is a subset of the input, so it would be more efficient to do any transformation in a reduced subset. For example:

```
=LET(f, FILTER(A2:C4, A2:A4=E1), IF(f="","",f))
```

or

```
=LET(f, FILTER(A2:C4, A2:A4=E1), IF(LEN(f),f,""))
```

Here is the output (having the referred Excel option marked):

[image: transforming the output]

By the way, this question should be marked as **duplicated** due to the following question: [Excel FILTER() returning 0 for blank cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64777658/excel-filter-returning-0-for-blank-cells), but I like more the answers provided here than in the referred link and also the OP of this question was more precise in its formulation than in the referred question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the `IF` function. `=IF(FILTER(Array, Array Conditions)=0, "",FILTER(Array, Array Conditions))`